# SQLite singleton class in Swift ( FMDB wrapper )

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

I am working on `Swift` singleton class to integrate `SQLite` easily ( Using FMDB wrapper class )

Simple methods to create database in directory, insert and fetch data.

Bridging support for FMDB Objective C usage in Swift.

```
let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: String(methodToCreateDatabase()!.absoluteString) )

if contactDB.open() {

    let insertSQL = strQuery

    let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,
                withArgumentsInArray: nil)

    if !result {
                print("Failed to add contact")
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        return false
    } else {
        print("Contact Added")
                return true
    }
} else {
     print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
     return false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift singleton manager class to integrate SQLite easily and quickly.**

**Source code** - https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/SQLite_SingleManagerClass

- SingleTonManager class
- Swift language
- Use of FMDB
- Array return for select statement
- Boolean flag for insert, update and delete statement

**Method to create database**

```
LocalDatabase.sharedInstance.methodToCreateDatabase()
```

**Method to insert, update and delete data**

```
if LocalDatabase.sharedInstance.methodToInsertUpdateDeleteData("INSERT INTO CONTACTS_TABLE (name, address, phone) VALUES ('Demo1', 'Demo2', 123)")
{
    NSLog("Store Successfully.")
}
else
{
    NSLog("Failled to store in database.")
}
```

**Method to select data**

```
LocalDatabase.sharedInstance.methodToSelectData("SELECT * FROM CONTACTS_TABLE")
```